# How to fake location iOS

Tags: ios, swift, location, gpx

I want to change real location (fake location) on iphone with out jaibreak (not Simulator).
So I think I can add GPX by code.
Any suggest or other solutions?

Comment: You can when running under the Xcode debugger, but not when you are running the app directly on the phone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @paulw11 says, you have to run your app from Xcode with the device tethered to a USB cable.

Create one or more GPX files and add them to the project. Then in the Xcode debug menu there is an option to simulate location. If you pick one of your GPX locations the device's GPS shows that location.

There is also a option in the scheme editor that lets you pick a default location to use on launch.

Comment: it 's mean: no way to add GPX by code ? And the only way to do that is connect iphone to Xcode by USB cable?
p/s: Thanks for your answer